# Android Unknown chromecast sdk error 2155

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm getting some strange behaviour where the session stops on the sender but keeps running in the receiver.

The callback onSessionEnded is called with error 2155 witch translates into unknown error.
Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks

Comment: FYI list of error codes which sadly does not include the `2155` https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes

Comment: Yeah that's why I came here to ask. It's very weird and started to happen only today

Comment: Did you find a solution, @tiagocarvalho92 ?

Comment: @JCarlosR Unfortunatly no :/

Comment: getting the same. anything?